# Crystallographic restriction

Tags: group-theory

Can someone give me a hint for the following problem:

What is the crystallographic restriction for a discrete group of isometries whose translation group $L$ has the form $\mathbb{Z}a$ with $a \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

I think this the the exercise of Artin Algebra chapter 6 5.2. It it follow the proof in 6.5.12.

*Proposition: Let G be a discrete subgroup of M. Let a be an element of its translation
group L, and let g be an element of its point group G. Then g(a) is in L.*

Let G be the discrete group of isometrics whose translation group L has the form $Za$ with $a≠0$ and let $g \in \overline G$ which is the point group of G.

From the proposition we know that any $a \in L, g(a) \in L$ so that $g(a)$ is in the form of $Za$ This mean that g can be only the rotation of $\pi$. So the Crystallographic restriction can only be $C_1$ and $C_2$ cyclic group.